# Does try-catch-throw adds any value over no exception handling at all?

Tags: c#, .net

If you have a method like this:

```
public int Foo()
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Assuming the exception is caught in another place, is this better than just having the method without any exception handling? Or this, on the other side, causes any disadvantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this better than just having the method without any exception handling?

No.  This does nothing for you other than pass the exception through, which is the default behavior.

Personally, I think it's a bad practice, as having a `try`/`catch` suggests that you're doing some form of exception handling or going to do *something* with the exception.

Comment: To add to this -- try/catching is for handling *known* or *expected* exceptions.  When you can take action on the exception.  Rethrowing an exception is useful if you need to do something (e.g. roll back) but then want to tell the caller of your function that an exception occurred.  If you are not planning to handle any exceptions (and being fault-tolerant/-ignorant and ignoring an exception counts as "handling"), then you shouldn't try/catch.

Comment: +0... also it is good answer to someone who just starting, but it is not entirely correct that it does nothing. Explicit try/catch prevent external caller to insert exception filter before finally of your code which could be interesting if you do things like run under other account.

Comment: Even if there is `...using(SecretEleveation()){...}` inside `try...catch`?

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, this doesn't change the behavior at all.

In the debugger, this gives you a place to put a breakpoint to break when an exception is thrown just in this one method. You can tell Visual Studio to break when certain exceptions are thrown, but that will break when they're thrown *anywhere*, not just in that one method.